# How can I construct this form "I'd like to know which book to read its summary"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions

The construction I want to form is `...which X to Verb "its" Noun`.

Specifically this question:
"How can I decide which book to read fully and which one to read only its summary?"

Is this question construction correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The form you have proposed is not correct and not idiomatic in English. To express the idea behind it, you can say:

"How can I decide which book to read fully, and which to read [only] a summary of?"

Another possibility is:
"How can I decide which book to read fully, and which book to read only as a summary."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/102816)

Comment: It answers the question as I understoood it. What was your understanding?

Comment: The OP asked "how" to construct a sentence. If you understood it as "give me a correct sentence" you shouldn't have answered it in the first place.

Comment: @CJDennis I disagree.  The OP asked the question (in their body) "Is this question construct correct", and Jack responded with "The form ... is not correct and not idiomatic ...", which is an answer to the question which was asked.  He then went on to offer additional suggestions, which if anything, he should be applauded for, not disparaged.

Comment: @Foogod "Is this sentence correct" questions are very low quality. They are unlikely to be helpful to anyone other than the OP. They're just proofreading questions. However, a question which is asking how to learn to fix mistakes is a good question because the OP can apply the skills learnt to (hopefully) an unlimited number of sentences. This answer does not even attempt to teach any skills, which I understand the OP to have requested. Yes, the questions asked in the title and the body are different. The one in the body is off topic, the one in the title in on topic and hasn't been answered.

Comment: "which I understand the OP to have requested" understand someone to have Verb+ed. Is there such a form as "understand someone to have done sth"? Could you link me to a reference?